# Rest API for 'Associate the sites with the hub' in Virtual WAN

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Hubs should generally be associated to sites that are in the same region that the VNet resides in.

On the VPN sites page, select the site or sites that you want to associate with the hub, then click +New hub association.

Required rest API for this

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the same question is answered in one of the MSDN threads.

Here is the link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/46564869-395c-41a6-a4be-62f435f063a2/rest-api-for-associate-the-sites-with-the-hub-in-virtual-wan?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork

"The portal uses REST API calls to do it. The easiest way is to do it is to get a HTTP debugger (like Fiddler) and do it in the portal, then go look at the Rest API calls the Portal uses to create the connection."

Hope this helps.